# jQuery UI: changing button text distorts button sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button in a form (which is styled with jQuery UI), and am dynamically changing the text with JavaScript. For some reason, changing the text makes the button size shrink to an unusual size. What can I do to remedy this?

Here is a picture of the problem:

---

[image: Different button sizes]

---

Comment: You need to post a working version on jsFiddle.  There are a LOT of reasons why this could have happened.

Comment: Often, re-initializing the button creator will fix these things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably change the text of the button the wrong way. For instance, if you simply do `$('#button').text('Test')` or `$('#button').html('Test')` you will overwrite the span element jQuery emits for styling purposes.

Try this:

```
$('#button').find('span').text('Test');
```

**EDIT**:

I just found a cleaner way to do this:

```
$('#button').button('option', 'label', 'Test');
```

Comment: finally!..It works perfectly and this theory solves lots of same kind of problems.