# Changing jQuery UI button text dynamically - Firefox inconsistent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have a jQuery UI button and I want to change its text dynamically. I've got no issue on Chrome and IE when I do this:

```
$('#myButton').find('span:first').text("myText");
```

However, Firefox seems to handle buttons differently and doesn't find a span for my button. So when on Firefox, I do that instead:

```
$('#myButton').text("myText");
```

**It works most of the times**, but sometimes, somehow my button isn't ready when I try to change its text, or maybe there's another reason that prevents Firefox to load the button correctly and I end up with a button like this: *(I spare you the numerous attributes added by jQuery UI)*

```
<button id="myButton">myText</button>
```

instead of that:

```
<button id="myButton">
  <span class="ui-button-text">myText</span>
</button>
```

and thus my button's styling goes wrong, just like in these threads: 
[Jquery UI button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599721/jquery-ui-button-issue) and
[jQuery UI: changing button text distorts button sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180945/jquery-ui-changing-button-text-distorts-button-sizing)

I have also tried this, following some advice found here:

```
$("#myButton).button('option', 'label', 'myText');
```

but I get an error saying I can't call button methods prior to initialization.

It's infuriating since Chrome and IE handle this perfectly every time. Is there a way to get a consistent behaviour ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you are using recent JQuery and JqueryUI versions that match together ?!

Comment: Yes, jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.3.